# Error parsing JSON file - Incorrect Object

Tags: javascript, php

I've replicated a graph script from one Wordpress installation to another

It operates using graph_nat and defs.php - Defs stores the DB details

I have not altered the script after migrating but now I'm getting JSON error

I've checked to ensure after object it's true

I'm struggling to figure out the bug, error reporting doesn't include the JSON error only false positives for PHP

```html
<?php

include ('../wp-load.php');
include ('defs.php');

// we need this so that PHP does not complain about deprectaed functions
error_reporting( 0 );
// Connect to MySQL

// constants stored in defs.php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", DB_NAT_USER, DB_NAT_PASS, DB_NAT_NAME);

// get user id
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

if ( $current_user_id == null || $current_user_id == 0) {
    $message = 'User not authorized';
    die( $message );
}

if ( !$db ) {
    die( 'Could not connect to database' );
}

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $message = 'Missing ID url parameter';
 die( $message );
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$practitionerId = $current_user_id;

$query = "SELECT results FROM submissions WHERE ID = ? AND practitionerId = ?";

$result = [];

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $practitionerId);
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $stmt->bind_result($results);
    
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result = $results;
    }
    
    $stmt->close();
}

// decode json from database
$json = json_decode($result, true);

$outputArray = [];
$healthIndex = 100;

if ($json) {
 foreach($json as $key=>$val) {

  $healthEvents = explode(", ", $val);
  
  // filter out empty strings
  $healthEventsFiltered = array_filter($healthEvents, function($value) {
   if ($value == '') {
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  });
  
  // points to decrease per event
  $healthDecrease = (count($healthEventsFiltered))*2;
  
  $healthIndex -= $healthDecrease;
  if ($healthIndex<0) {
      $healthIndex = 0;
  }
  
  // implode array to get description string
  $arrayString = implode(",<br>", $healthEventsFiltered);
  
     // age groups
     $ageGroup = $key*5;
  
  $ar = array("category" => "Age: " . $ageGroup, "column-1" => $healthIndex, "events" => $arrayString);

  array_push($outputArray, $ar);
 }
 echo json_encode($outputArray, true);
} else {
 $message = 'Could not decode JSON: ' . $result;
 die( $message );
}

// Close the connection
mysqli_close( $db );
?>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @itssajan Error parsing JSON file: /scripts/graph_nat.php?id=undefined

Comment: Figured it out, I wasn't passing USER ID in url. Silly me

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I wasn't passing USER ID in url. It was undefined. I should go back to school